# Rails form (form_for) using jQuery Moobile toggle switch

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-mobile, form-for

I have a form_for in rails which is basically:

```
<%= form_for(@pin) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area  :content, placeholder: "Narrate your story..." %>
    <%= f.select :privacy, [['Private', true], ['Public', false]] %>
<% end %>
```

But I want to turn my privacy select drop-down into a jquery mobile toggle switch which uses the [following jquery format](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/switch/):

```
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

My privacy values get input into the database as a Boolean true/false with a default of true. I am having trouble accomplishing this using the f.form_for in rails.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. With a little help from firebug, I just transformed that part of the form into pure html without help from rails:

```
<select name="pin[privacy]" id="pin_privacy" data-role="slider">
    <option value="true">Private</option>
    <option value="false">Public</option>
</select>
```

Simple as that! If anyone has the "rails" solution, would love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Move form to a partial:
Example: app/views/robots/_form_content.html.erb

```
<%= form_for robot, :html => {dataajax: false, multipart: true} do |f| %>
```

Sub "dataajax" for "data-ajax":
Example: app/views/robots/_form.html.erb

```
<%= raw(render("robots/form_content").gsub("dataajax","data-ajax")) %>
```